# Extracting fasta ids after string match

Tags: perl, grep

I have a list of fasta sequences as following:

```
>Product_1_001:299:H377WBGXB:1:11101 
TGATCATCTCACCTACTAATAGGACGATGACCCAGTGACGATGA
>Product_2_001:299:H377WBGXB:2:11101 
CATCGATGATCATTGATAAGGGGCCCATACCCATCAAAACCGTT
```

The original fasta sequence is much longer than the subset posted here. I wanted to extract the 10 characters after the pattern "TCAT" into a separate file and did this

```
grep -oP "(?<=TCAT).{10}"
```

I do get the needed result as:

```
CTCACCTACT
TGATAAGGGG
```

I would like their corresponding fasta ids as one column and the extracted pattern as second column like:

```
>Product_1_001:299:H377WBGXB:1:11101     CTCACCTACT
>Product_2_001:299:H377WBGXB:2:11101     TGATAAGGGG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one-liner

```
perl -lne ' /^[^<].+?(?<=TCAT)(.{10})/ and print $p,"\t",$1; $p=$_ ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat fasta.txt
>Product_1_001:299:H377WBGXB:1:11101
TGATCATCTCACCTACTAATAGGACGATGACCCAGTGACGATGA
>Product_2_001:299:H377WBGXB:2:11101
CATCGATGATCATTGATAAGGGGCCCATACCCATCAAAACCGTT

$ perl -lne ' /^[^<].+?(?<=TCAT)(.{10})/ and print $p,"\t",$1; $p=$_ ' fasta.txt
>Product_1_001:299:H377WBGXB:1:11101    CTCACCTACT
>Product_2_001:299:H377WBGXB:2:11101    TGATAAGGGG

$
```

Comment: The fasta file is much longer than the example I posted, so it does not work by splitting into array mode

Comment: yes.. the second solution doesn't use arrays you can use that

Comment: Tried did not work. The sequence has the header in the first line, and the sequence in the second line.

Comment: looks like you changed the input like.. they were coming in single lines.. let me check

Comment: @zdim.. updated.. the initial qstn was having both the lines in single line.. so I used that..

Comment: Right, that was probably about editing (separate lines show together unless some markup is used).  removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be ussing `awk` command like this :

`cat <your_file>| awk -F"_" '/Product/{printf "%s", $0; next} 1'|awk -F"TCAT" '{ print substr($1,1,35) "\t" substr($2,1,10)}'`

the output :

```
Product_1_001:299:H377WBGXB:1:11101     CTCACCTACT
Product_2_001:299:H377WBGXB:2:11101     TGATAAGGGG
```

hope it help you.

Comment: input file changed.. check the question again

Comment: one fasta record consists of 2 lines.. please check if your output is matching with the OP

Comment: thanks @stack0114106, I can't edit now, to fix the last  @user1834063 can use this command :
`awk -F"_" '$1 == "Product" {printf "%s", $0; next} 1' file2.csv  | awk -F"TCAT" '{ print substr($1,1,35) " " substr($2,1,10)}'`

Comment: something like this should work ````awk -F"TCAT" ' /^>/ { p=$0;next } /TCAT/ { print p, substr($2,1,10) } ' fasta.txt```` give a try and update the answer